Featured Image add tab
I was wondering if there's a hook/function to add a new tab to the Featured image modal window as shows in the picture below:
I've found this thread How to add new tab to media upload manager with custom set of images?, but the answers from there didn't work for me.

WordPress does not have a built-in hook or function on the PHP side that allows you to directly add a new tab to the Media Library Modal window. To achieve this, you need to use JavaScript to modify the media uploader interface.
You can add a custom tab to the WordPress Media Library modal by using JavaScript to extend the media frame. Here’s a quick example:
JavaScript Code:
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var originalMediaTabs = wp.media.view.MediaFrame.Select.prototype.browseRouter;
    wp.media.view.MediaFrame.Select.prototype.browseRouter = function(routerView) {
        originalMediaTabs.apply(this, [routerView]);
        routerView.set({
            'new-tab': {
                text: 'New Tab',  // Tab title
                priority: 100
            }
        });
    };

    wp.media.view.MediaFrame.Select.prototype.on('router:new-tab', function() {
        this.content.set(new wp.media.view.AttachmentsBrowser({
            controller: this,
            collection: new wp.media.model.Attachments(),
            selection: this.state().get('selection'),
            model: this.state()
        }));
    });
});

PHP Code:
function my_custom_media_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'my-custom-media-scripts',
        plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'js/admin.js', // Path to your JS file
        array('jquery', 'media-views'), // Dependencies
        null,
        true
    );
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_media_scripts');

This JavaScript code adds a new tab called "New Tab" to the Media Library modal window. The PHP code enqueues the JavaScript on admin pages.
